# Class that extends JPanel isn't displaying in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have two classes, `Interfaz` which extends `JFrame`, and `Contenido` which extends `JPanel`. I'm simply trying to add a `Contenido` object to the `Interfaz` `JFrame` (which I do in `Interfaz`'s constructor), but when I run the code (`Interfaz` is my main class) the `Interfaz`'s `JFrame` window appears but the `Contenido` `JPanel` doesn't show up in there, even though I added it to the `JFrame`. Anybody know why this is happening?
The `Interfaz` `JFrame` is empty, but the `Contenido` `JPanel` has a `JLabel` and a `JTextArea`. I also made it so that "Clicked" is printed in the output window whenever I click the `JPanel`.

Sorry for the long codes, I'm using netbeans' GUI builder for both classes and it adds a lot of code.

*Interfaz.java*

```java
package contenidodirectorio;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Interfaz extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Interfaz() {
        initComponents();
        contenidoPanel = new Contenido();
        add(contenidoPanel);
        contenidoPanel.setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 502, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 420, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Interfaz().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
    private JPanel contenidoPanel;
}
```

*Contenido.java*

```java
package contenidodirectorio;

public class Contenido extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public Contenido() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                formMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        jLabel1.setText("Directorio:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(48, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 224, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(48, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(101, 101, 101)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(82, 82, 82)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(156, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        System.out.println("Clicked.");
    }                                 


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration
```

Comment: `GroupLayout` is not a developer friendly layout manager.  You'd be much better off ditching the UI form editor and learning to deal with layouts manually

Comment: Start with [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: `contenido` is being added directly to the frame and not to the `GroupLayout` - Corrections: do not use that layout manager for `Interfaz` (default `BorderLayout` should work well); **or**, correctly add `contenido` to the layout manager (probably drag&drop in IDE, I usually do layouts by *hand* to have better control)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, I'll give that a check when I have the time. I've already had my share of problems with GroupLayout, like all my components moving around when I only try to move a text box, so I have been thinking of going for GridBagLayout.

Comment: just tested the second option of my comment, works fine: move creation of `contenidoPanel` one line up; remove the `add` statement; add `addComponent(contenidoPanel)` to both groups (vertical, horizontal) ((despite I would still prefer `BorderLayout` for the frame itself - more *logical* IMO (must agree with MadProgrammer, I never used `GroupLayout` myself, but for testing it)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger That did the trick, thanks a lot. I'm gonna start trying out other layouts and see which one I get comfortable with, thanks for the help.

Comment: I often use `GridBagLayout` - learning it is not that easy, but it is very powerful. The others, excluding `GroupLayout` and `SpringLayout`, are almost straightforward